# "Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls" failing to compile

Tags: mschart

I wish to view the samples in the "Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls" code available on the Microsoft website. However when I try to build the project in order to create an exe that I can open, I get the following error:

> Cannot write to the output file "obj\Release\System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Utilities.SampleMain.VerticalTabPageButton.resources". The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Am I missing something here? How am I supposed to navigate this set of samples?

Oh, and I manually edited the .sln file so it opens in VS2008. But I don't think that has anything to do with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when trying to unzip the "Samples Environments for Microsoft Chart Controls.zip" file.

I was attempting to unzip to my "Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Project" folder. Obviously this folder is quite far down a directory structure on the PC, so I received the same error.

So here's the solution: unzip the file to somewhere quite high up your PC's directory structure - for example, the root of your c drive, i.e. "c:\".

You'll then find you don't receive the "Path Too Long" error message.

Best wishes,
Mike.